# Hide border-right when scroll comes using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKnxZ.png)

I want to hide border when vertical scroll comes.Please help.

Comment: Please add your HTML in your question and I will post the answer for the same.

Comment: And how do you want to behave if the content exceeds its permitted height ?

Comment: compare the client width with the scroll width of the element to check if the scroll bar is there or not. If it is there then hide the border.

Comment: Are you interested in finding out when a vertical scroll bar can be seen or when the content is scrollable because it is too high? (Eg on mobiles you won’t necessarily have a visibly scroll bar)

Answer (score 0):

If y-overflow is set to auto, then it's not easy (possible?) to detect when scrollbar is created. You would have to use the container height. So if you know that the scrollbar will appear once the container height > 500px, Js can set the style of the element to remove the border (or better it could apply a class that forced "border-right:none !important"). And when height <=500, remove that style again so that the border is returned.
As for when JS does the checking? It depends when that text is placed in the container - if it happens a load time, check the height once on page load, and then on document resize. It it loads later (async or ajax or whatever) you will have to perform the check again as soonas the text is added to the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that functionality like this.

**Steps**

1. Select the container or div.
2. And create a function that keeps checking whether div's scrollHeight is bigger or clientHeight,
   if the scroll height is bigger than client height it means that there is a
   scrollbar.
3. And use ResizeObserver to observe the change in heights
   doc link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

**Note**: Try to resize window to see the effect or play around with height.

```js
// selecting the div
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div');

// checking should remove the border or add
const shouldRemoveBorder = () => {
 const hasVerticalScrollbar= myDiv.scrollHeight>myDiv.clientHeight;

if(hasVerticalScrollbar) {
  myDiv.style.borderRight = "none"
} else {
   myDiv.style.borderRight = "1px solid"
  }   
}

new ResizeObserver(shouldRemoveBorder).observe(myDiv)
```

```css
.my-div {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```